# titrating a weak acid with strong base in the present of buffer

Tags: titration, buffer

I would like to get a neutral salt solution for a weak acid whose pKa is 3.42. This weak acid is in the form of solution (now is 20% w/w), thus I cannot directly dissolve the powder into the buffer etc. And I would like the resulting solution to be as concentrated as possible.

I am thinking to titrate the acid with NaOH (1M) or other bases (that only generates the salt of the acid and water). After calculation, I found that 2.0998 ml of NaOH will give me around pH 7.4 (which is what I want as it is to be used in a biological system). The problem is that: it is very difficult to accurately add 0.0998 ml of NaOH. And I found that 0.0001 ml of NaOH deviation will lead to huge changes in pH, however, I want to make sure the final pH is between 7.2 - 7.4.

Another consideration is I would want to avoid using pH meter because I would like to maintain the solution as sterile as possible (which I will prepare everything in a biological hood).

In short, I would like to know how to prepare a neutral solution for that acid precisely, e.g. through calculations of the exact volume of base needed or use diluted NaOH (though I still want the resulting salt solution to be as concentrated as possible). I would like to know whether it would help if I add some buffer to the system (e.g. PBS that is often used in biological experiments)?

Comment: I can't say I get what you really want there. If you added enough buffer it would give you any pH you'd want, but it would hardly be a solution of acid, but rather its salt.

Comment: Is it possible to use a pH meter?

Comment: If you make $\pu{1 M}$ solution of pure conjugate base of your acid, its $\mathrm{pH}$ would be roughly 8.7.

Comment: Phosphate Buffer Saline (PBS) is a neutral buffer in physiological $\mathrm{pH}$.  Thus, I'd expect if you use it to dissolve the pure conjugate base of your acid, the solution $\mathrm{pH}$ might be between 7.2 - 7.4 as you expected. You may need to use a  $\mathrm{pH}$-meter to check the  $\mathrm{pH}$. You can adjust the  $\mathrm{pH}$ using either dilute $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{HCl}$ solutions.

Comment: Thank you for all of your replies, I have edited the question and hope that has clarified the problem. In short, I would like to avoid using pH meter and I cannot dissolve any "powder".@Mathew Mahindaratne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something, but a rough reality check says that if you are thinking of adding 2.0998 mL of 1 N NaOH solution, you have ~0.0021 moles of base, which for a good buffer, should have about ~0.0021 moles of acid. If your acid solution is 20% by weight, and guessing 200 for a molecular weight, your total acid volume is 2.0998 mL also. It seems to me that your accuracy problem with the base is in addition to the accuracy problem with measuring the acid.

Unless the acid is very expensive (isotope?), scale up! In your sterile hood, make 2 batches of the buffer solution, starting with 50 mL of the 20% acid in each vessel (of about 200 mL capacity). Add 51 mL of 1 N NaOH solution to one and 49 mL of 1N NaOH solution to the other. Measure the pH of both by using an eyedropper to take out a few mL for a regular pH meter, or just one drop to place on a micro pH meter, such as

[image]

https://news.thomasnet.com/fullstory/pocket-ph-meters-utilize-non-glass-silicon-chip-sensor-608720

One of the 100 mL solutions may be exactly what you want. If not, it would be nice it their two pHs straddle your desired pH. Using an eyedropper, transfer some of one solution into the other, stir, and check the pH by withdrawing a drop to test on the micro pH meter. The pH electrode will never be immersed into the buffer. When you get one of the solutions to the pH you need, you can still save the residue for further adjustments.

Some micro pH meters claim to be able to measure as little as 5 microliters, so if the acid is very expensive, you could scale down.

Calculations are very fine for exams and theorizing, but when it comes down to needing an exact pH near 7, you may have to take other variables into consideration, including the preparation, i.e., bringing the calculations into reality. If you *calculate*, you are guessing you will get it right. If you *measure*, you'll know if you got it right. (Assuming you calibrate the pH meter, and it works as expected, etc., etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! And yes, the acid is quite expensive... It seems using a pH meter is necessary for my problem, though I always find calibrate the pH meter is super complicated. But I will definitely try!

Another follow-up question will be: if I ultimately use the neutralized solution as a concentrated stock solution, and the final concentration is let's say 100-fold diluted in PBS/ culture medium. Do you think the buffer function in these solvents can tolerate the extreme pH (e.g. pH 10 if I over titrate, or pH 3 if I added a little bit less NaOH)?